# How to answer a question that asks to verify the correctness of the code?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, downvote-reason

Reference: [An answer is an answer. Even if one line is enough.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266955/3137699)

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190527/3137699) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31190484/3137699) today.

The *"TL;DR"* version of the question was

> *I don't see any issue. Do you?*

The *"TL;DR"* version of my answer was

> *I don't see any issue in this code. It's fine.*

**with** a probable reason for the issue and a tip to improve the code.

I got two downotes (and NAA and/or VLQ flags, too, maybe), presumably under the category

> *"This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post"*

Please let me know, what is the practice followed here to answer a question asking to verify the correctness of the code. AFAIK,

Comment: Well that's definitely an answer.  Perhaps two separate people just thought it was wrong, or at least not helpful.  I'm personally not familiar enough with the nitty-gritty of c to know.

Comment: I would down/close vote immediate.  SO is not a test and verification house.  We do not run test specs or issue certificates of conformance.

Comment: @MartinJames well, I respectfully disagree. Everybody is not an expert. They may be confused about the correctness of the code. YMMV. :-)

Comment: Define 'correctness'..

Comment: @MartinJames sure. A correct code will be standard-conforming, without any possible UB, should be producing a defined O/P with a defined behavior, while compiled (`C`-ish, sorry) with a standard-conforming compiler. Anything more you would like to add/remove?

Comment: 'defined O/P with a defined behavior' requires running tests against a spec.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298303/is-it-allowed-to-ask-if-my-code-is-correct-in-stack-overflow

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks. Somehow, this makes the question valid on SO, so, my question here stands. :-)

Comment: @MartinJames well, for a code snippet of that length, I guess a simple walkthrough code-review would do. after all, its only 5 lines of code, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't open the question to look:)

Comment: Isn't it a bit misleading to completely leave out the fact that the question is not so much about checking the code, but rather asking what's up with the output of a code analysis/profiling tool?

Answer (score 3):

What that question is really asking for is not a confirmation of correctness or a code review but an explanation of the error.

This is explicitly in the question now, but was certainly a requirement of a good answer even when the question was first asked (unless you are taking the question ridiculously literally, in which case the answer could just have been "no").

As such, your answer (pre-edit) did not answer the question well (and arguably didn't answer it at all).

Answer (score -1):

Such question are off-topic.  A demonstration of 'correctness' would require a functional and/or test specification with the question.  Already, it would be TL;DR for SO format, never mind the impracticality of SO contributors running tests:(

Comment: Sorry, I disagree to your view. Moreover, my question is mainly about the answer quality. Nothing personal, though. :-)

Comment: @NatashaDutta - I know that.  We just have a difference of opinion:)

Comment: Appreciate it. It's a pleasure (and a learning experience, also) to have a difference of opinion with people like you who actually care to explain things. Thanks much. :-)